# How to deal with "warning: ignoring return value of ‘system’, "

Tags: c, bash, shell, gcc

I need to run some bash shell commands when my c program reaches to a certain point. What I have found by googling is that system() provides such a functionality. However, compiling the code by gcc generates a warning message like below and the bash command does not get executed. Any solution or alternative?

```
warning: ignoring return value of ‘system’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
system(command);
```

Comment: See the answer. Just assign it to a variable. It should work then.

Comment: As for why the command does not fire, that's another question.

Comment: If the command isn't getting executed it isn't because of that warning.

Comment: You could try:  `(void) system("do something")`.  This works for unused variables.  I'm having a hard time reproducing the unused return value warning, so I wasn't able to confirm it will fix your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a library call, and you are ignoring the return value from it, thats why that compiler warning. Assign it to a variable, check the return value ([See man page of system](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system)). And that warning has nothing to do with your bash command not getting executed.

Comment: You can do all sort of things with that variable. Compare it with 1, or 0, and see if the library call executed successfully. See the man page of system.